# Help with picklist on vf page

Tags: apex

I am using a picklist on vf page, i am putting option values on the vf page. Is there any way to put values in picklist using my class ?
 vf page :

```
<apex:page controller="myclass">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageblock>
    <apex :pageblocksection>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selected}">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="+" itemLabel="+"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="-" itemLabel="-"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="/" itemLabel="/"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="*" itemLabel="*"/>
        </apex:pageblocksection
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:selectList> 
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list on your controller. And then pass that list on the vf page like this :

```
public List<SelectOption> getmyOptions()
    {
    List<SelectOption> selectOptionList=new List<SelectOption>();
        selectOptionList.add(new SelectOption('+','+'));
        selectOptionList.add(new SelectOption('-','-'));
        selectOptionList.add(new SelectOption('/','/'));
        selectOptionList.add(new SelectOption('*','*'));
        return selectOptionList;
    }
```

And on the vf page you can use this as :

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!selected}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!myOptions}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

Let me know if this helps. you can use this link to know more about selectlist : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOption.htm

Answer (score 1):

MyClass :

```
public String fields { get; set; }
       List<SelectOption> optns=new List<SelectOption>();
        public list<selectoption> getvalues(){
           optns.add(new SelectOption('FirstName','FirstName'));
            optns.add(new SelectOption('LastName','LastName'));
            optns.add(new SelectOption('Email','Email'));
            optns.add(new SelectOption('Phone','Phone'));                        
            return optns;
        }
```

page:

```
       <apex:selectList value="{!fields}" multiselect="true" size="3">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!values}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!OptionList}"/>
```

Controller:

```
public List<SelectOption> getOptionList() 
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('+', '+');
    options.add(new SelectOption('-', '-');
    return options;
}
```